# Equivalent formulation of convex functions

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I came across an equivalent formulation for convexity of a function and that is a function f is convex if and only only
$f(y+$$\beta$$(y-x))$ $\geq$ $f(y)$ + $\beta$$.$$(f(y)-f(x))$ where $x,y$ $\in$ Domain($f)$ and $\beta$ is such that $y+$$\beta$$(y-x)$ $\in$ Domain($f$). $\beta$ is non negative. What can be a geometrically convincing arguement to believe in this inequality?

Comment: This looks like a reformulation of the standard inequality (bring $f(x)$ to the other side and divide by $1+\beta$). However, there seems to be a problem: From this property you cannot conclude that the domain of $f$ is convex---just consider $f$ with $\operatorname{Domain}(f) = \{x, y\}$ with $x \ne y$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Even if I am given that $Domain(f)$ is convex, I am unable to make sense of it geometrically. Any ideas on that?